# Gauge markup ready for dynamic content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the markup for a gauge to display how full a messages inbox is, but I'm having some trouble specifically with the dynamic part.

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    margin: 35px 35px 35px 50px;
}

#gauge {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;

    background-color: #5E767D;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    height: 260px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
    
    #gauge div {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #gauge #current {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 900;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #gauge #percentual {
        background-color: #FFF;
        font-weight: 800;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="gauge">
  <div id="current" style="height: 15%; top: 5%;">85</div>
  <div id="percentual" style="height: 85%;">100%</div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsmm62ru/) ;)

This updated version, cleaner than previous works much better as I don't need to manipulate the **top** property in such a weird way like before, however it only works when the *current* value is **85** or lower. o.O

The logocs behind this new markup I came to is:

- The value of *current* as **height** of *percentual*;
- The difference between them, as **height** of *current*;
- The **height** of *current* minus 10% as **top** for *current* to stick the number to the bottom, keeping them both close, in the middle;

How could I fix this in order to make it work regardless the numbers used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is not very well centered as I would like, but at least I don't have text overlapping anymore and the logics remains simple:

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    margin: 35px 35px 35px 50px;
}

#gauge {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  background-color: #5E767D;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  height: 295px;
  margin: -7px 0 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

    #gauge .current {
      display: block;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 900;
      top: -15px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

      #gauge .current span {
        position: relative;
        top: 100%;
      }

    #gauge .percentual {
      background-color: #FFF;
      display: block;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }

      #gauge .percentual span {
        margin-left: -2px;
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="gauge">

  <div class="current" style="height: 10%; top: 0%">
    <span>90</span>
  </div>

  <div class="percentual" style="height: 90%;">
    <span>100%</span>
  </div>

</div>
```